# The usage of relative pronoun "that"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I want to know what difference in usage these sentences have?

> 1)This hair that grows every morning until it touches the floor(original)
>   2)This hair grows every morning until it touches the floor

I guess first sentence emphasize that her hair is unique.

If you have to know what was before this sentence you are welcome:

> So today, I'll make myself look as adorable as possible to welcome him again then he 'll cut my hair

Maybe it refers to "my hair" in this sentence

Comment: Please don't say that "that" is a relative pronoun. It's not -- it's a subordinator.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st one is not an independent sentence. It may be the part of a sentence, where the NP (*"the hair"*) is followed by a subordinate defining relative clause (*"that grows every morning"*) and an adverbial clause (*"until it touches the floor"*).

The 2nd one is an sentence.